# CRM data import error 0x80040265

Tags: dynamics-crm

I try to upload new Account with the data import wizard via a csv file, the only column is the Account Name. I always received the error code 0x80040265 with no log on the server.  I do the same thing for Contact with more columns and it works without errors.
Someone have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot, a plugin crashed for each account record into the csv file, it's not normal that there are no log...